# Code-Design : Can I write the code to update the last modified date of the entity inside the method that persists an entity?

Tags: coding-style, dao, separation-of-concerns, single-responsibility-principle, clean-architecture

Let's say I have an entity:

```
Employee { 
  _id,
  name,
  lastModifiedTimeStamp 
}
```

and a method to persist it . This persist method can be called from anywhere.

```
boolean persist(Employee e ){
.... 
<code to save to db>
...
}
```

Now if I need to write code that updates the lastModifiedTimeStamp. Is it a violation of Single Responsibility Principle if I write it inside the persist method.

```
boolean persist(Employee e ){
.... 
<code to save to db>
...
<code to update lastModifiedTimeStamp>
...
}
```